# Acentos EditText Android

Tags: java, android

alguém ai sabe como posso e se da pra fazer o seguinte, em meus EditText queria o usuário não pudesse colocar acentos.

No caso seria melhor tratar o texto e remover depois da digitação?

Comment: Poderia colocar alguma parte do seu código? O que você já tentou fazer...

Comment: Na realidade, eu não sabia nem por onde começar, mas a reposta do Fernando ajudou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solução 1 ([`InputFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html))**

Você pode utilizar [`InputFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) para esse fim, sendo a implementação algo assim:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                               Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            // Não tenho certeza se esse método "Character.isLetterOrDigit" restringe todos os acentos como você espera, mas no seu caso você pode substitui-lo pelo seu método.
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

**Solução 2 ([`digits` do `EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits))**

Outra possibilidade é você informa quais as entradas que você permite, no atributo [`digits` do `EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits), podendo ser algo similar a isso:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm" />
```